# Is there a way to export objects to a package by script?

Tags: c#, object, unity-game-engine

I know you can make in the Editor menu: Assets > Export Package...
But if you have a lot of objects it will take some times to find what you want to export as package. there is no a search option in the Export window.

But in the Hierarchy you can search for specific object/s but you can't make them package from the search.

I searched in the Hierarchy for example for door_lo and the result:

[image: Doors]

But how can I copy or make a package of this objects so I can use them easy in other project/s ? I can make one by one as prefab then copy them from the hard disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it's a good way but it's working as I wanted.
Searching for objects creating a prefab with the searched objects as childs.
Now I can copy the prefab to another project/s.

Two fields: One for searching one for the prefab name
Two buttons: One for the searching one for generating the prefab

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class GeneratePrefab : EditorWindow
{
    private string prefabName = "";
    private string objectsToSearch = "";
    private static GeneratePrefab editor;
    private static int width = 350;
    private static int height = 200;
    private static int x = 0;
    private static int y = 0;
    private Vector2 scroll;
    private int count = 0;
    private List<GameObject> foundObjects = new List<GameObject>();
    private bool usePrefabName = false;
    private bool searched = false;

    [MenuItem("Window/Generate Prefab")]
    static void ShowEditor()
    {
        editor = EditorWindow.GetWindow<GeneratePrefab>();

        CenterWindow();
    }

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        GUI.Label(new Rect(10, 10, 80, 20), "Prefab Name");

        if (usePrefabName)
        {
            GUI.enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            GUI.enabled = false;
        }
        prefabName = GUI.TextField(new Rect(10, 30, 150, 20), prefabName, 25);

        GUI.enabled = true;
        GUILayout.Space(55);
        usePrefabName = GUILayout.Toggle(usePrefabName, "Use prefab name");

        GUI.Label(new Rect(10, 90, 150, 20), "Search by name");
        objectsToSearch = GUI.TextField(new Rect(10, 110, 150, 20), objectsToSearch, 25);

        if (objectsToSearch != "")
        {
            GUI.enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            GUI.enabled = false;
        }
        GUILayout.Space(90);
        if (GUILayout.Button("Search"))
        {
            count = 0;
            foreach (GameObject gameObj in GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<GameObject>())
            {
                if (gameObj.name == objectsToSearch)
                {
                    count += 1;
                    foundObjects.Add(gameObj);
                }
            }

            if (foundObjects.Count > 0)
            {
                searched = true;
            }
            else
            {
                searched = false;
            }
        }

        GUI.enabled = true;
        if (count > 0)
            GUI.TextField(new Rect(10, 130, 60, 20), count.ToString(), 25);

        if (searched)
        {
            GUI.enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            GUI.enabled = false;
        }
        GUILayout.Space(0.1f);
        if (GUILayout.Button("Generate Prefab"))
        {
            GameObject go = new GameObject();
            for (int i = 0; i < foundObjects.Count; i++)
            {
                foundObjects[i].transform.parent = go.transform;
            }

            if (usePrefabName == true)
                go.name = prefabName;

            PrefabUtility.CreatePrefab("Assets/" + go.name + ".prefab", go);
            DestroyImmediate(go);

            objectsToSearch = "";
            searched = false;
            count = 0;
        }
    }

    private static void CenterWindow()
    {
        editor = EditorWindow.GetWindow<GeneratePrefab>();
        x = (Screen.currentResolution.width - width) / 2;
        y = (Screen.currentResolution.height - height) / 2;
        editor.position = new Rect(x, y, width, height);
        editor.maxSize = new Vector2(width, height);
        editor.minSize = editor.maxSize;
    }
}
```

Comment: Careful! If I understand you correctly you just copy the prefab to other projects, right? What about all dependencies like scripts, mesh data, materials, images etc? This approach won't work.

Comment: @derHugo You right. When creating a prefab of a gameobject it's not creating the whole object with all the dependencies ? I did some test added Cube to my hierarchy and created prefab of it and it's creating the prefab of the Cube. The main idea is to make recovery. In my case in one project I have a package of a space station and by accident I deleted all the doors. So I have the space station package also in another project so the idea is to copy back the doors from the second project to the original.

Comment: @derHugo Maybe I'm missing something here. The main idea is to make recovery when deleting by accident some objects and copy them back again from another project. I don't mind if I did changes stuff on the doors and lost them the idea is to recover the doors by it's original doors from the original package.

Comment: Well it is possible to use that as long as you have al dependencies e.g. the entire modell and material data in both projects (with the same AssetIDs!). It only works fine for a Unity default Cube because Unity already *knows* the mesh data for that. Same for Unity' default components like e.g. Transform. And it might work in your special case since you have your original mesh data in both projects. **BUT: For recovery I'ld rather suggest you start using [Git](https://git-scm.com/) or something similar!**

Answer (score 2):

This might help you.

```
//path will be the path folder of this files
private void ExportFiles(string path)
{
   string [] prefabFiles = Directory.GetFiles (path, "*.*"); 
   //string [] prefabFiles = Directory.GetFiles (path, "*.prefab");
   string exportPackage = targetFolder + "/exportpackage.unitypackage";
   ExportPackageOptions exportFlags = ExportPackageOptions.Default|ExportPackageOptions.Interactive | ExportPackageOptions.Recurse;
   AssetDatabase.ExportPackage (prefabFiles, exportPackage, exportFlags);

}
```

Comment: this looks promising. But isn't `ExportPackageOptions.Default` and `ExportPackageOptions.Recurse` kind of contradicting?